# Error in Pyspark when Insert data in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark code. .and when I am trying to insert data into HIVE Table from pyspark, I am getting error. I tried finding on google but no-idea what's wrong.

When I run this insert statement directly into HIVE, it runs fine but using spark, its giving the error.
my insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE QA_Result VALUES( 'Table_100_columns_tiny', 's3a://rbspoc-sas/sas_100_columns_tiny.csv', 'default', 'Yes', '210', '210', '(COL51=32.1000000),(COL62=17.8000000),(COL7=71393.5482355),(COL47=21.3000000),(COL58=17.1000000),(COL39=29.7000000),(COL55=8.0000000),(COL49=40096.1000000),(COL8=-1782477.8622806),(COL66=21.2000000),(COL28=6.2920000),(COL31=4851.1877388),(COL17=5.2860000),(COL27=5.0800000),(COL42=5493.3000000),(COL6=-5707379.1906659),(COL20=3.6720000),(COL38=15.4000000),(COL32=4.8200000),(COL60=23.9000000),(COL63=23.5000000),(COL36=5.1340000),(COL25=5.5390000),(COL43=17.1000000),(COL57=21.1000000),(COL46=23.0000000),(COL52=26.0000000),(COL14=5.0780000),(COL16=5.5300000),(COL40=19.3000000),(COL45=22.9000000),(COL21=6.0570000),(COL15=4.7380000),(COL9=4.6110000),(COL10=4.1230000),(COL5=180.0000000),(COL13=6.0490000),(COL37=14.9000000),(COL24=5.5730000),(COL64=29.3000000),(COL35=4.9500000),(COL26=4.8420000),(COL19=5.3460000),(COL53=14.5000000),(COL56=16.6000000),(COL11=6.2100000),(COL50=43.2000000),(COL61=18.6000000),(COL44=22.4000000),(COL33=4.4690000),(COL29=2.3800000),(COL48=22.7000000),(COL22=3.9550000),(COL34=5.2160000),(COL18=3.4470000),(COL12=5.4570000),(COL59=31.7000000),(COL23=5.0200000),(COL41=15.6000000),(COL30=4.3820000),(COL54=19.3000000),(COL65=34.2000000)', '(COL51=32.1000000),(COL62=17.8000000),(COL7=71393.5482355),(COL47=21.3000000),(COL58=17.1000000),(COL39=29.7000000),(COL55=8.0000000),(COL49=40096.1000000),(COL8=-1782477.8622806),(COL66=21.2000000),(COL28=6.2920000),(COL31=4851.1877388),(COL17=5.2860000),(COL27=5.0800000),(COL42=5493.3000000),(COL6=-5712141.0954278),(COL20=3.6720000),(COL38=15.4000000),(COL32=4.8200000),(COL60=23.9000000),(COL63=23.5000000),(COL36=5.1340000),(COL25=5.5390000),(COL43=17.1000000),(COL57=21.1000000),(COL46=23.0000000),(COL52=26.0000000),(COL14=5.0780000),(COL16=5.5300000),(COL40=19.3000000),(COL45=22.9000000),(COL21=6.0570000),(COL15=4.7380000),(COL9=4.6110000),(COL10=4.1230000),(COL5=180.0000000),(COL13=6.0490000),(COL37=14.9000000),(COL24=5.5730000),(COL64=29.3000000),(COL35=4.9500000),(COL26=4.8420000),(COL19=5.3460000),(COL53=14.5000000),(COL56=16.6000000),(COL11=6.2100000),(COL50=43.2000000),(COL61=18.6000000),(COL44=22.4000000),(COL33=4.4690000),(COL29=2.3800000),(COL48=22.7000000),(COL22=3.9550000),(COL34=5.2160000),(COL18=3.4470000),(COL12=5.4570000),(COL59=31.7000000),(COL23=5.0200000),(COL41=15.6000000),(COL30=4.3820000),(COL54=19.3000000),(COL65=34.2000000)', '(COL3=5),(COL4=25),(COL67=8),(COL68=8),(COL69=8),(COL70=8),(COL71=8),(COL72=8),(COL73=8),(COL74=24),(COL75=8),(COL76=8),(COL77=8),(COL78=8),(COL79=8),(COL80=8),(COL81=8),(COL82=8),(COL83=8),(COL84=8),(COL85=8),(COL86=8),(COL87=8),(COL88=8),(COL89=8),(COL90=8),(COL91=8),(COL92=8),(COL93=8),(COL94=8),(COL95=8),(COL96=8),(COL97=8),(COL98=8),(COL99=8),(COL100=2)','(COL3=5),(COL4=25),(COL67=8),(COL68=8),(COL69=8),(COL70=8),(COL71=8),(COL72=8),(COL73=8),(COL74=24),(COL75=8),(COL76=8),(COL77=8),(COL78=8),(COL79=8),(COL80=8),(COL81=8),(COL82=8),(COL83=8),(COL84=8),(COL85=8),(COL86=8),(COL87=8),(COL88=8),(COL89=8),(COL90=8),(COL91=8),(COL92=8),(COL93=8),(COL94=8),(COL95=8),(COL96=8),(COL97=8),(COL98=8),(COL99=8),(COL100=2)', '2', '1', 'Fail','2018-02-04 07:31:30','2018-02-04 07:31:52','Data match is different. 2 row(s) are not in target and 1 row(s) are not in source,, Average values are different for columns [COL6]')
```

Error is:

```
-chgrp: '' does not match expected pattern for group
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...
-chgrp: '' does not match expected pattern for group
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...
```

For reference: CREATE TABLE statement is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE QA_Result (
    TableName String,
    SourceDB String,
    TargetDB String,
    StructureValidation String,
    SourceRecordCount BigInt,
    TargetRecordCount BigInt,
    SourceAverage String,
    TargetAverage String,
    SourceStringLength String,
    TargetStringLenght String,
    SourceDataDiff BigInt,
    TargetDataDiff BigInt,
    Status String,
    StartDateTime Timestamp,
    EndDateTime Timestamp,
    Comments String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

Comment: What is location of QA_Result table ?

Comment: It is in S3 AWS

Comment: You may check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12378 , may be aws jars are required to add in spark.driver.extraClassPath

Comment: From spark, it is able to extract data from hive table which has S3 underlying storage. Its the write to hive causing issue via spark.

Answer (score 0):

The hadoop-common [code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/0b8464d75227fcee2c6e7f2410377b3d53d3d5f8/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java#L326) will print directly to `stderr` and is not using any logger, so you cannot suppress this in a conventional way. However, you can set your own process's `stderr` stream to a custom class and suppress the errors (worked for me):

```
System.setErr(new SuppressErrors("org.apache.hadoop.fs"))
```

while this is `SuppressErrors` class:

```
class SuppressErrors(packages: String*) extends PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err)) {

  def filter(): Boolean =
    Thread.currentThread()
      .getStackTrace
      .exists(el => packages.exists(el.getClassName.contains))

  override def write(b: Int): Unit = {
    if (!filter()) super.write(b)
  }

  override def write(buf: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int): Unit = {
    if (!filter()) super.write(buf, off, len)
  }

  override def write(b: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
    if (!filter()) super.write(b)
  }
}
```